# Prove integration inequality

Tags: integration

$f(x)=\int_x^{x+1}$$\sqrt{\arctan t}$ $dt$. I need to show that for every $x\ge 0.$
$f(x)<\sqrt{\arctan(x+1)}$

I don't know from where to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about the Riemann interpretation of the integral thanks to the area under the curve.

The function $\sqrt{arctan}$ is a positive and increasing function on the positive numbers. Therefore the area under the curve between $x$ and $x+1$ is less than the area of the rectangle with basis $[x,x+1]$ and height $\sqrt{arctan(x+1)}$. Hence $$f(x)=\int_x^{x+1} \sqrt{arctan(t)}dt < (x+1-x)\sqrt{arctan(x+1)} = \sqrt{arctan(x+1)}.$$

Comment: Ok. I caught the idea, but can you explain me how you get the first inequality that you wrote. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

By Mean Value Theorem

$$f(x) = \arctan c (x+1-x) = \arctan c$$ with $c \in (x,x+1)$. As $x \mapsto \sqrt{\arctan x}$ is increasing $\arctan c <\sqrt{\arctan (x+1)}$, hence the conclusion.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\arctan\left(x\right)$ is a monotone increasing function we have $$f\left(x\right)=\int_{x}^{x+1}\sqrt{\arctan\left(t\right)}dt\leq\sqrt{\arctan\left(x+1\right)}\int_{x}^{x+1}dt=\sqrt{\arctan\left(x+1\right)}.
 $$